# Webpack Module Federation - Invalid or unexpected token when importing component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I'm trying to set a project using Module Federation but currently it breaks when I try to load the component, but when I run the host project it throws me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" whenever I try to import the component. This is how I'm imoprting the component:

```
const OtherComponent = lazy(async () => await import("app1/App"));
```

which is declared in the module federation config as

```
app1: "app1@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js",
```

And on the other project it is declared as

```
name: "app1",

remoteType: 'var',
  exposes: {
    "./App": "./src/App",
  },
  filename: "remoteEntry.js",
```

[This is the project that's importing](https://github.com/CRamos132/module-federation) and [this is the one that exports](https://github.com/CRamos132/module-federeation-app)

Comment: In your app that is using the remote url do you have a remoteType property set? If you do remove it.